# Shouldn't the Android standard SDK API 20 be suggested in the SDK manager?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want to download the Android SDK API 20 through the SDK Manager.

However, only the "wear" version (for watches etc.) is present: **4.4W.2 (API 20)**
Not the standard version I'm looking for: 4.4.2 (API 20).

Here's a screen showing the possible options:

[image]

Why isn't it present?

Comment: 4.4.2 is API 19, not 20.

Comment: Ok, so what should I download if I got this from my IDE (IntelliJ): **Please install Android target 20 (the Android newest SDK)**

Comment: The newest is API 21

Comment: I tried with the API 21, but the IDE complains about the same warning. He expects "target 20"..

Comment: If you aren't developing for Android wear, then that sounds like a bug in Android Studio. I recommend upgrading to the newest version (v0.9.1) and if the issue still isn't resolved reporting a bug at http://b.android.com

Comment: Actually, I'm using the famous Intellij-plugin Phonegap/Cordova to run a Ionic app.

Comment: well there is your problem you are using Phonegap and not native java

Comment: @tyczj What is the benefit of your point?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Please install Android target 20 / but I expect the 19](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849745/please-install-android-target-20-but-i-expect-the-19)

Comment: @tyczj It was me... ;) (the "duplicate"), but it's clearly not a duplicate, since my OP deals with the SDK Manager display.

Comment: Why would you post a duplicate 2 hours later? With nearly 10k rep you are expected to be a trusted user and should know better

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, but I will delete the previous one, since I have more clues with this post.

Comment: @Mik378 no it clearly is a duplicate just reworded but still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, only the "wear" version (for watches etc.) is present: 4.4W.2 (API 20)
>   Not the standard version I'm looking for: 4.4.2 (API 20).

That is because there is no "standard version". API Level 20 is 4.4W, for Android Wear devices. There is no API Level 20 for non-Wear devices, nor will there ever be one.

> Ok, so what should I download if I got this from my IDE (IntelliJ): Please install Android target 20 (the Android newest SDK)

The one that is showing in your SDK Manager, as 4.4W.

Comment: Does the "wear" version fits Cordova app? I've read that wear was built for Android watches and gadgets like those.

Comment: @Mik378: Since Android Wear does not support `WebView`, I am not aware that you can write a Cordova app for Android Wear. "I've read that wear was built for Android watches and gadgets like those" -- yes, Android Wear is for "Android watches and gadgets like those".

Comment: That's the whole point :) IntelliJ expects me to use "target 20", but only "wear" version is API 20, as you claimed. Strange..

Comment: @Mik378: You are going to have to figure out where in your project files the "20" is coming from. IntelliJ itself is oblivious to all of this -- your problem is stemming from your plugin. In standard Android development with the IntelliJ-based Android Studio, your error would come from a `compileSdkVersion 20` line in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Yes, I will investigate ;)

Comment: Indeed, some `project.properties` files specified `target-20`. I replaced with `target-19`.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK versions are specified in [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html), in the `<uses-sdk>` section.

For Phonegap, the values that populate this are specified as preferences in [config.xml](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File).

I suspect that you've specified "20" as the value for `android-minSdkVersion`.

Comment: `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />` I have this in my `AndroidManifest.xml`. So, I don't figure out why my IDE warns about the need of SDK 20.